# Conditionally select multiple items by date range and identifier in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, date-range, posixct

I have a `data.table` containing unit identifiers, a setting identifier, and a data range for which this setting is valid. I need to extract the settings for specific unit identifiers for a specific day. The following minimum working example shows how I would obtain the result.

```
library(data.table)
settingstable=data.table(UNITID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,6),
                     STARTDATE=as.POSIXct(c("2018-01-01","2018-02-28","2018-06-01","2018-01-01","2018-04-01","2018-06-01","2018-01-01","2018-01-01","2018-01-01","2018-01-01","2018-05-01")),
                     ENDDATE=as.POSIXct(c("2018-02-28","2018-05-31","2018-12-31","2018-03-31","2018-05-31","2018-12-31","2018-12-31","2018-12-31","2018-12-31","2018-04-30","2018-12-31")),
                     SETTINGS=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11))
selectunits=c(2,4,6)
selectdays=as.POSIXct(c("2018-04-02","2018-05-03","2018-02-01"))

resultsettings=NULL
for (i in 1:length(selectunits)) {
  resultsettings=rbind(resultsettings,settingstable[UNITID==selectunits[i] & STARTDATE <= selectdays[i] & ENDDATE >= selectdays[i],.(UNITID,SETTINGS)])
}
```

For large data.tables or large amounts of units and days this will be very inefficient. I was hoping that a grouping with `by=UNITID` would work, but unfortunately this is not possible as the following will result in a `longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length` error.

```
resultsettings=settingstable[UNITID %in% selectunits & STARTDATE <= selectdays & ENDDATE >= selectdays,.(UNITID,SETTINGS),by=UNITID]
```

How can I improve my code so it runs more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a non-equi join:

```
settingstable[.(u = selectunits, d = selectdays), 
  on=.(UNITID = u, STARTDATE <= d, ENDDATE >= d), 
  .(UNITID, SETTINGS)]

   UNITID SETTINGS
1:      2        5
2:      4        8
3:      6       10
```

The syntax is `x[i, on=, j]`.

- The list `i = .(u = selectunits, d = selectdays)` is treated as a table, to be joined to `x = settingstable`.
- The join works by looking up each row if `i` in `x` according to `on=`.
- In `j`, we can transform the result. (Without `j`, we'd just get the joined table.)

If your `on=` conditions yield multiple matches, they will all appear in the result. If they leave no matches, `SETTINGS` and other columns from `x` will be NA (though this can be tweaked using the `nomatch=` argument).